# Use Hashmap for ListView Android

Tags: android-listview, hashmap, android-arrayadapter, custom-arrayadapter

I have some problem with my code, I want to display the results from con.execute into the ListView
How to use this Hashmap for Listview?

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container, false);

        // Untuk menjalankan API Mikrotik
        ApiConnection con = MainActivity.getCon();
        if (con !=null) {
            try {
                List<Map<String, String>> rs = con.execute("/log/print");
                for (Map<String, String> r : rs) {
                    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewLog);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getActivity(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
                }

            } catch (MikrotikApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        return view;
    }
```